# Which one's better for performance in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am so confuse when to use switch to gain better performance.
Here's the code I want to compare.
I would like to ask you which one's better cause i'm using this script in 50 object

```
 void FixedUpdate()
    {
        tabrakan();
    }

    void tabrakan()
    {
        switch (ayam)
        {
            case 0:
                if(perubahan == 0)
                {
                    transform.Translate(userDirection2 * movespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(perubahan == 0)
                {
                    transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

vs

```
   void FixedUpdate()
    {
        tabrakan();
    }

    void tabrakan()
    {
      if (ayam == 0 && perubahan == 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(userDirection2 * movespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else if (ayam == 1 && perubahan == 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }
```

which one's better?

Comment: Unity has a profiler doesn't it? Race your horses. However, the difference would be negligible. Worry about other things

Comment: I dont see any difference that's why im asking

Comment: Switch can be better in some situations as it works on a table (though likely not this situation), however it depends on the compiler how this is implemented. If you cant see a difference, then you don't have a problem... chose your favorite

Comment: A switch statement is usually more efficient than nested if statements (Compiler creates a jump table) - But as Marc stated the difference is very small and ultimately you should instead worry about readability. If your code is slow it is not because you used an if chain instead of a switch - If you worry about fast code, check which algorithms you use and their average case / worst case running times - that will be a much better way to increase performance

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Actually the improvement you get by using `userDirection * (movespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime)` is way higher then your decision between `switch` or `if` for a simple `bool` with two cases. ^^ `userDirection * (movespeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime)` does one simple `float * float`multiplication + one `Vector3 * float` while you are doing `Vector3 * float` and with the result a second `Vector3 * float` .... you see .. what you are asking is such a minimal improvement that it takes more effort then it solves ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, from a performance perspective this *isn't going to matter* in 99.9% of code, unless this is in a tight loop and all of the other things are incredibly cheap. Frankly, stop trying to micro-optimize, and worry about correctness instead *until* you have performance data that suggests that this is an issue, based on real profiling or benchmarking.

Anecdotally, in many cases `switch` is marginally faster as it is a single jump rather than multiple tests (branches) and jumps, *however*, this is like saying:

> if I drive from New York to Boston, when I get to the building I'm going to, which door will it be quicker to use?

It *doesn't matter* - that isn't where the time was spent.